# Pagination in Wagtail

Tags: django, pagination, blogs, wagtail

I'm fairly new to Wagtail, and I am in the process of creating a site that will have a Resources (blog) section and I'm not sure how to implement pagination so that there are only 5 posts on each page and the user has to click a number (1, 2, 3, etc.) to go to the next page to see the next 5 posts.

I have this in my template for the pagination section of the resource/blog index page:

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

What code do I need to incorporate to make this functional? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Django provides the module `django.core.paginator` for this purpose: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/ . Using this within Wagtail is very similar to the examples in the Django documentation - the only real difference is that when you're setting up the `Paginator` object to be passed to the template, you do that with a `get_context` method on the page model, instead of a view function. Your model definition will look something like this:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

class ResourceIndexPage(Page):
    # ...
    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super(ResourceIndexPage, self).get_context(request)

        # Get the full unpaginated listing of resource pages as a queryset -
        # replace this with your own query as appropriate
        all_resources = ResourcePage.objects.live()

        paginator = Paginator(all_resources, 5) # Show 5 resources per page

        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            resources = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
            resources = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
            resources = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        # make the variable 'resources' available on the template
        context['resources'] = resources

        return context
```

Within your template, you can now loop over the items using `{% for resource in resources %}`, and display the pagination links as follows:

```
<ul class="pagination">
  {% if resources.has_previous %}
    <li><a href="?page={{ resources.previous_page_number }}"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>
  {% endif %}
  {% for page_num in resources.paginator.page_range %}
    <li {% if page_num == resources.number %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="?page={{ page_num }}">{{ page_num }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
  {% if resources.has_next %}
    <li><a href="?page={{ resources.next_page_number }}"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
  {% endif %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that I have used the following around the last `<li></li>` to only show the next arrow if there is a next page - `{% if resources.has_next %} {% endif %}`

Comment: Nice. This works really well. Is there any way to update this so I can use nice urls that have /page/1/ in? Currently I am hacking around but it's pretty messy!

Comment: @Designer023 Check out `RoutablePageMixin`: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/contrib/routablepage.html

Answer (score 5):

I very much appreciate that you got me here - thanks so much for the assist.  I had to make some adjustments to make it work. Here's the model if anyone comes across the same issue:

```
class NewsIndexPage(Page):
intro = RichTextField(blank=True)

def get_context(self, request):
    context = super(NewsIndexPage, self).get_context(request)

    # Get the full unpaginated listing of resource pages as a queryset -
    # replace this with your own query as appropriate
    blogpages = self.get_children().live().order_by('-first_published_at')

    paginator = Paginator(blogpages, 3) # Show 3 resources per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        blogpages = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        blogpages = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        blogpages = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    # make the variable 'resources' available on the template
    context['blogpages'] = blogpages

    return context
```

...and here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    {% if blogpages.has_previous %}
      <li>
        <a href="?page={{ blogpages.previous_page_number }}"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for page_num in blogpages.paginator.page_range %}
      <li {% if page_num == blogpages.number %} class="active"{% endif %}>
        <a href="?page={{ page_num }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if resources.has_next %}
      <li>
        <a href="?page={{ blogpages.next_page_number }}"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
      </li>
      {% endif %}
  </ul>
```

It works like a charm - and adds to the learning curve!

Answer (score 1):

In case it's useful to anyone, I wanted this to work as closely as possible to the [class-based view ListView](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.list/ListView/), and so I ended up with this:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, InvalidPage
from django.http import Http404
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

from wagtail.core.models import Page

class ArticleListPage(Page):

    # Some Page variables set here. #

    # Pagination variables:
    paginator_class = Paginator
    paginate_by = 10
    page_kwarg = 'page'
    paginate_orphans = 0
    allow_empty = False

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)

        queryset = Page.objects.live()

        paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(
                                        queryset, self.paginate_by, request)
        context.update({
            'paginator': paginator,
            'page_obj': page,
            'is_paginated': is_paginated,
            'object_list': queryset,
        })

        return context

    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, page_size, request):
        """
        Adapted from the ListView class-based view.
        Added the request argument.
        """
        paginator = self.paginator_class(
                                    queryset,
                                    self.paginate_by,
                                    orphans=self.paginate_orphans,
                                    allow_empty_first_page=self.allow_empty)
        page_kwarg = self.page_kwarg
        page = request.GET.get(page_kwarg) or 1

        try:
            page_number = int(page)
        except ValueError:
            if page == 'last':
                page_number = paginator.num_pages
            else:
                raise Http404(_("Page is not 'last', nor can it be converted to an int."))
        try:
            page = paginator.page(page_number)
            return (paginator, page, page.object_list, page.has_other_pages())
        except InvalidPage as e:
            raise Http404(_('Invalid page (%(page_number)s): %(message)s') % {
                'page_number': page_number,
                'message': str(e)
            })
```

This will give you the same `paginator`, `page_obj`, `is_paginated` and `object_list` variables in your template that you would get with a normal Django ListView.

(Using python 3, Django 2.1 and Wagtail 2.3.)