# Pagination in Wagtail with {%for %} cycle

Tags: django, python-3.x, wagtail

I have some problem with understanding django pagination in Wagtail cms.
I read this topic [Pagination in Wagtail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40365500/pagination-in-wagtail)

So it is not works well for me.
In my templates for get products i use this code

```
                {% for product in page.get_children.specific %}
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="single-best-receipe-area mb-30">
                        {% image product.product_photo width-400 %}
                        <div class="receipe-content">
                            <a href="{% pageurl product %}">
                                <h5>{{ product.title }}</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

and then:

```
    <ul class="pagination">
        {% if product.has_previous %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ product.previous_page_number }}"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% for page_num in product.paginator.page_range %}
        <li {% if page_num == product.number %}class="active" {% endif %}><a
                href="?page={{ page_num }}">{{ page_num }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if product.has_next %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ product.next_page_number }}"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
```

in my models.py i use this:

```
class ProductsPage(Page):
body = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, help_text = 'Описание страницы')
product_image = models.ForeignKey(
    "wagtailimages.Image", 
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name='+',
    help_text='Фотография Категории'
    )
content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
    ImageChooserPanel('product_image'),
]
def get_context(self, request):
    context = super(ProductsPage, self).get_context(request)
    all_product = OneProduct.objects.live()
    paginator = Paginator(all_product, 1) # Show 3 product per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        product = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        product = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        product = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

# make the variable 'product' available on the template
    context['product'] = product

    return context
```

finally i saw pagination but there are all products on every page
i understand that problem is in this part of template

```
{% for product in page.get_children.specific %}
```

because i take all products.But how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your context variable will be correct in your template.
You might try to get all products `all_products = OneProduct.objects.all()`

Not the best, but working example of pagination. It might help you.

```
paginator = Paginator(data, amount) # amount of products per page
page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)
page = paginator.page(page_number)
is_paginated = page.has_other_pages()

if page.has_previous():
    prev_url = '?page={}'.format(page.previous_page_number())
else:
    prev_url = ''

if page.has_next():
    next_url = '?page={}'.format(page.next_page_number())
else:
    next_url = ''

last_url = '?page={}'.format(page.paginator.page_range[-1])
```

And pass `page` to your context variable `context ={'page_object': page}`.

So you can use this for cycle `{% for product in page_object.object_list %}`